# quick jQuery question

Tags: javascript, jquery

Should be a really quick one for you pro's:

I'm learning to use JS, in particular a plugin called (embarassingly) 'Easy Image'.

http://cssglobe.com/post/3783/jquery-plugin-easy-image-or-content-slider

Here's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/tomperkins/LnES6/

JS files are from here:
http://cssglobe.com/post/3783/jquery-plugin-easy-image-or-content-slider
And obviously jQuery (1.5)

I've stripped it down to the basics and can't figure out why it's not working.

Any tips are much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: the javascript and images you want to test in jsFiddle aren't available in the jsFiddle's scope - maybe this is the case ;)

Comment: jQuery 1.5 is recent, have you tried latter versions?

Comment: Really Quick Answer: please include the relevant code in your question and explain what's `not working`. More people are likely to help you that way.

Comment: Sorry guys, here's a link to an online version: http://customstudiodevelopment.co.uk/jquery-test/

Comment: @yoda: I think you mean `earlier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery.js and easySlider.js gets an Server error 500 when the browser tries to load them from

http://customstudiodevelopment.co.uk/jquery-test/

Verify that the files are there and that they can be loaded

http://customstudiodevelopment.co.uk/js/jquery.js

http://customstudiodevelopment.co.uk/js/easySlider.js

Unless both these urls load the right JS files your code will not work ...

As a general tip, get FireBug addon to firefox, with the Net panel I found this error in less than 30 seconds ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help David, it's often the simple things!

Answer (score 0):

In menu on the left you have to set your framework to JQuery and in Add resources box add 'Easy Image' script. Then comment out first two `<script>` tags (you will need them on your site but not on jsFiddle). Also change `src` attributes in `<img>` tags to absolute path because there is no images folder nor any images on jsFiddle site.

**Edit**
This is what you get with `<script>` tags on your site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
2<html><head>
3<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
4</head><body>
5<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
6<p>The server encountered an internal error
```

Script doesn't work because there are no scripts on your site (both links are dead).

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<base href="http://customstudiodevelopment.co.uk"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-test/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-test/js/easySlider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider").easySlider();
});
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Gallery Test</title>
<link href="/jquery-test/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider">
 <ul>
   <li><img src="/jquery-test/images/Website-Strip_Future.png"></li>
  <li><img src="/jquery-test/images/SR-Toomer_small.png"></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<!-- /end #slider -->
</body>
</html>
```

Note, I put the base element in there to test on my desktop. It's not required for it to work on your server, but if it's on your desktop computer, it should work (so you can copy the html into a Notepad file and save with filetype .html and run it locally to test).

It appears as if your file includes (js/css/image) are not pointing to where you want them to be.

Use Firebug to test these types of things. When you open the console, you can inspect the scripts included, including open each included file. In this way, you can doublecheck to make sure the browser is able to get to your included files.

http://getfirebug.com/

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/File:Script_Panel.png <<< see del-linkrolls.js close to top, right; that's where you select which file to inspect

Answer (score -2):

When I loaded the page I got an ".ready() is not a function" which would mean you are not loading jQuery.  Then again I've never fooled around with jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle shows an include to the jQuery library (filepath relative to the OP's server).